# how to retrieve archived messages from openfire using smack api in java?

Tags: java, openfire, smack

### Getting Archived Messages

I don't know how to retrieve the archived messages , i have used monitoring Service plugin which combines Open Archive .I can see the archived messages in the OpenFire GUI.

---

I googled about it and got to know that smack doesn't provide the facility and i have to create a **custom stanza** to communicate with **open-fire**.
I don't know how to create Custom Stanza using java and how to comprehend the reply... plz help

Answer (score 0):

Create a ExtensionElement by using ExtensionElement class in your class  and override the method implementation, you can also
read more about smack [Provider Architecture](http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/docs/latest/documentation/providers.html)